# How to debug on VS Code? "Bad file descriptor" error

Tags: python, pyspark, visual-studio-code

It looks basic, however I'm having a real hard time debugging a py file using VS Code + Anaconda:

```
import sys
print(1)
```

The output error is below

> Exception has occurred: exceptions.IOError (9, 'Bad file descriptor') 
>   File "C:\Projetos\projetos\vinculacao\teste.py", line 3, in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened 'coz I was with 2 distincts Anaconda versions. I just removed all of them and reinstalled Anaconda on the ProgramData folder, as suggested by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print ("1")
```

I hope this solves the problem :)

Comment: Haha It doesn't. Somehow VS Code is not able to find the libraries or something like this that I'm trying to figure out. When  I try on a Notebook on Databricks it runs perfectly.